# Смещение курсора через статический элемент

Tags: winapi

Есть диалоговое окно, в котором находится один статик элемент. 
Для того чтобы определить смещение мышки, я запоминаю ее предыдущее положение и сравниваю с текущим. Смещение происходит от -1 до 1 по координатам х и у, не важно с какой скоростью перемещаться по окну. Но когда я быстро перемещаюсь курсором через статическое поле, то смещение возрастает и становится больше чем -1 и 1. Как это избежать?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <vector>
BOOL CALLBACK DialogProcedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

INT WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE /*previous*/, LPTSTR /*commandLine*/, INT showCommand)
{
    return DialogBox(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, DialogProcedure);
}

//положение статического окна относительно диалогового
RECT GetStaticRectPosition(HWND window, HWND staticElement)
{
    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(window, &windowRect);

    RECT staticRect;
    GetWindowRect(staticElement, &staticRect);

    RECT clientRect;
    GetClientRect(window, &clientRect);

    RECT staticPosInParent{};

    //размер клиентской области не меняется.поэтому рассчитываем его один раз
    static int windowRectWidth = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    static int windowRectHeight = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;

    static int clientRectWidth = clientRect.right - clientRect.left;
    static int clientRectHeight = clientRect.bottom - clientRect.top;

    static int nonClientWidth = (windowRectWidth - clientRectWidth) / 2;
    static int nonClientTitle = windowRectHeight - clientRectHeight - nonClientWidth;

    staticPosInParent.left = staticRect.left - windowRect.left - nonClientWidth;
    staticPosInParent.top = staticRect.top - windowRect.top - nonClientTitle;
    staticPosInParent.right = staticPosInParent.left + staticRect.right - staticRect.left;
    staticPosInParent.bottom = staticPosInParent.top + staticRect.bottom - staticRect.top;

    return staticPosInParent;
}


struct DIRECTIONS
{
private:

public:
    DIRECTIONS()
    {
        set.push_back(POINT{ -1, 0 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ 1, 0 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ 0, 1 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ 0, -1 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ 1, 1 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ -1, -1 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ -1, 1 });
        set.push_back(POINT{ 1, -1 });
    }
    std::vector < POINT> set;
};


bool operator==(POINT P1, POINT P2)
{
    return P1.x == P2.x&&P1.y == P2.y;
}
BOOL CALLBACK DialogProcedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL result = false;

    static HWND staticElement;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(window, 0);
        break;
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        staticElement = GetDlgItem(window, IDC_STATIC);
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        static POINT prev = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        POINT cur = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };

        RECT rect = GetStaticRectPosition(window, staticElement);

        if (PtInRect(&rect, cur))
        {
            POINT delta = { cur.x - prev.x, cur.y - prev.y };


            if (delta.x != 0 && delta.y != 0)
            {
                if (find(dir.set.begin(), dir.set.end(), delta) == dir.set.end())
                {
                    TCHAR context[50];
                    _stprintf_s(context, TEXT("Error: X: %d, Y:%d"), delta.x, delta.y);
                    SetWindowText(window, context);
                }
            }
        }
        prev = cur;
        break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Кода много, а суть непонятна. Вы хотите мышкой перемещать статик в пределах родительского окна. И при резких движениях мыши -
 увеличивается погрешность: мышь сдвигается относительно статика. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: погрешность увеличивается только когда мышка перемещается в пределах статика. если ею просто двигать по окну, погрешность не меняется.

Comment: Логично, вы же перехватываете `WM_MOUSEMOVE` у основного окна. При перемещении мыши над статиком, сообщение уходит уже статику. `SetCapture(window)` решит проблему, если ее вызвать в начале перемещения, а `ReleaseCapture` - в конце.